# harmonic mean of column in pandas

Tags: pandas, error-handling

---

I have over 300 .csv files that I am sending through a for loop in this program. The data is indexed by time and I have split each file into a morning and afternoon dataframe. I want to find the harmonic mean of the Velocity (kts) column in each dataframe. I'd like to then send the hmean through an if statement to test for velocity ranges.

Here is my code:

```
df0 = df.iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).indexer_between_time(time(10),time(23))]  
df2 = df.iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).indexer_between_time(time(0),time(10))]          
v_afternoon = df0['Velocity(kts)'].apply(hmean, axis=None).reset_index()
v_morning = df2['Velocity(kts)'].apply(hmean, axis=None).reset_index()
```

I am getting the error:

ValueError: Harmonic mean only defined if all elements greater than zero

I am wondering if this is a range issue, as within these 300 files there are missing values. I have done a manual search of these outputs and can't find any negative velocities. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use the `isnull` method of the `DataFrame` or `Series` objects to see whether there is missing data. `s = df0['Velocity(kts)']` and then `s[s.isnull()]` will give you the rows with missing values.

Comment: Thank you. There was a lot of missing data. Do you know if there is a way to only take the hmean of the data present? I tried using dropna but the data quality is so low that it emptied whole dataframes.

Comment: You can use `subset` argument of `dropna` to choose a subset of columns to look at for dropping missing items. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html